# Looking to count the number of times a company name appears in a column, while excluding a duplicate value in another column

Tags: arrays, function, excel-formula, countif

```
Spreadsheet column setup:
A:Name      B:Hours      C:Client       D:Invoice#       E:Date

Joe    8      Acme     123     8/21/18

Bill   12     Zorg     456     8/19/18

John   9      Acme     123     8/21/18

Ben    15     Acme     987     8/5/18
```

I want to count the number of jobs we did for a client for the month.

Each individual job is denoted by the invoice number. A job may have multiple people on it so the same invoice number will be duplicated in column `D`.

I'd like exclude those duplicates so I get a true count of jobs for a particular client regardless of how many people were actually on the job.

Using the example above, if I ask for total number of "Acme" jobs this month, I need the output to read 2 (since invoice 123 had a couple guys on it) not 3 due to it not excluding the duplicate invoice number.

Nothing I try or search on the internet like function CountIf quite meets my unique parameters.

Please advise, Thank you.

Comment: You can count unique values by combining `Job ID` and `Invoice #`. You can use that formula to remove duplicates or set up a pivot table

Comment: @Quoc: I'm not quite sure I understand. Is "Job Id" a function in excel as its not one of my headers? What would the formula look like and will it give a numeric count of the number of individual jobs for a specified client in column C while counting only 1 associated invoice number from column D?